# Set JWPlayer User-Agent?

Tags: javascript, html, jwplayer

Is it possible to set the user agent in JWPlayer ? I have a streaming link that checks to see if the user is on an ipad, and will only work if this is the case. In VLC, I can set the player declare itself an ipad. Just wondering if this is possible with JWPlayer

Comment: This isn't possible that I know of in the JW Player. Do you have an example of how VLC does it?

Comment: Any solution here.?